# how to "split" up my dedicated server to run a hosting business?

Tags: web-hosting

i want to offer hosting from my dedicated server.

```
Intel Core2Quad Q9300
8gb DDR2
750gb SATA
10mbps
2000gb
Ubuntu Hardy - 64 bit
```

What software can I use to "split" the server so that I can have like clients use the hosting.

Comment: What type of hosting: web, email, application, etc.?

Comment: it will be used for web hosting

Comment: Do you want a full suite of software that allows people to "sign-up" for accounts and so forth?  Or are you just needing to check out Apache's Virtual Hosting features?

Comment: i want a full suite of sotware that lets people to sign up for accounts, and automatically configure the server to support the new client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need any software beyond what's required to serve the sites.  Shared hosting is just a matter of creating a user account for each customer, configuring vhosts to serve their stuff, and then watching the cash roll in[1].

If you want to do VPS hosting, then you'll need a virtualisation system like [KVM](http://linux-kvm.org) or [Xen](http://xensource.com/).

1. Disclaimer: Cash rarely rolls, and web hosting cash doubly so.

Comment: i've heard about KVM and Xen. is there a software that makes it easy to run shared hosting ?

Comment: Heaps of them, but I'm not a fan of any of them.

Comment: where can i find these ? what should i be googling for ? shared hosting virtualization software ?

Comment: Do you want shared hosting, or do you want virtual machine hosting?  Software to manage the former are typically called "shared hosting control panels".

Comment: shared hosting sounds good. okay googling.

Comment: You might want to look at Webmin & Virtualmin.